# Why does get_as_dataframe work differently when worksheets change?

Tags: nan

Beginner in Python. After reading a specific worksheet in a spreadsheet, I usually check if the data is imported correctly by printing the dataframe. However, there are some worksheets that output values as NaN even when the cells have a number. It does not happen with every other worksheet. What is the difference?

When printing the value of a single cell, the output was as expected.
When I copied the whole data to a new worksheet, the output was as expected and the values were indicated normally.
When I changed the name of the original worksheet, the output was as expected and the values were indicated normally.
I'm starting to think that GAS is related with this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Feels kind of odd to answer my own question... but it seems like this problem occurs when the name of the worksheet is a cell address. Let me know if there are other situations.